# main in my NSOperation subclass not being called

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I subclassed NSOperation and implemented the main method. When I added it to an NSOperationQueue, it was not being called. I compared it to sample code and sample projects that *do*
work and could not see what the problem was. Does anyone have any experience with this problem and what causes it, please?

After going crazy trying to find the problem, I decided to start over from scratch, rebuild my class and test it at each step. In the header, I declared it a subclass of NSOperation. In the implementation file, I implemented main and only put a couple of lines: `sleep(3)`; `NSLog..;`. All good. Each step worked as I started to add properties, even declared delegate, etc.

Finally, in the main, I put code to use NSDirectoryEnumerator.  Suddenly, main was not being called at all.  Not only that, when I took that code back out, it still does not work!!  I tried restarting XCode 4, restarting my machine (not that I know why these might help, but I'm running out of ideas) but all to no avail.

Any clues at all would be most appreciated. Thanks.

---

Update: I started over (again!) from scratch but this time I assembled the parts in a different order... and now it works!  However, in case there is something that I'm doing wrong anyway and I've just been lucky this time round, here is the @interface section as @Andrew suggested:

```
@class ScanOperation;

@protocol ScanOperationDelegate 
-(void)fileFound:(ScanOperation *)operation;
-(void)finishedScanOperation:(ScanOperation *)operation;
@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ScanOperation : NSOperation {
@private
    NSObject <ScanOperationDelegate> *delegate;
    NSURL *rootUrl;
    int totCount, dirCount, filCount, errCount;
    NSTimeInterval elapsed;
}
- (id)initWithScanRootUrl:(NSURL *)startAtUrl;

@property (readwrite, assign) NSObject <ScanOperationDelegate> *delegate;
@property (readonly) int totCount, dirCount, filCount, errCount;
@property (readonly) NSTimeInterval elapsed;
@end
```

Comment: it would help to see the @interface  section to make sure that you subclassed it properly

Comment: I built it back up from scratch but this time in a different order and it works... however, I'll paste in the @interface anyway in case someone notices something that's not right:

Comment: Is your `NSOperation` subclass concurrent? `-main` is automatically invoked only if the operation is **not** concurrent.

Comment: "non-cooncurrent" means that I've written my custom subclass and then implemented a `- (void)main` inside the `@implementation` block, right? If so, that is what I did. What is mystifying is why exactly that `main` was called until I made some changes and then, even after I tried to undo those changes, it still wasn't being called. Now it gets called because I started from the simplest possible implementation (my `main` had only `sleep(3); NSLog("I've finished");` and then went from there

Comment: I'm guessing your -(void)main method signature might not've been right. Note it's not (int)main() as with the main() of a standard C program. - this is an instance method with a void return and no arguments -(void)main ...

Comment: noted! The next time it happens, I will paste the exact code. I appreciate it's difficult to work out what's wrong without the actual code. I thought that perhaps that the way `NSOperation` subclassing works is very "fragile" and that others had experienced something similar and knew what the common cause(s) was (were).

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen too. As usual it was me: I hadn't initialised the OperationQueue for the Operation to run on.

Answer (score 0):

I met this question just now. 
1) initialize the OperationQueue
2) add your operation to this queue
3) clean your project
4) run